# How to prove the limit of "the exponential of a sequence"

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, exponential-function

So given a convergent sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with limit $a$, I'd like to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n=e^a.\quad(1)$$

Knowing that $e$ is defined by

$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n,$$

the relationship in $(1)$ certainly not unintuitive, and also very useful, but how do I prove it?

In the case of a constant sequence $a_n=k\;\forall n$, it's pretty straightforward as you can write

$$\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\exp\left[\log\left(\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\right)\right]=\exp\left[n\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right]=\exp\left[\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)}{1/n}\right]$$

and then taking the limit you can apply L'Hôpital's rule to differentiate the numerator and denominator separately and then get the result after a few manipulations. 
But since 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \log\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)=\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{xf(x)+x²}$$
I will need to know the derivative $(a_n)'$ with respect to $n$ of the sequence, to use this approach, which is not necessarily well-defined. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: You don't need $a_n'$. In the expression $n\log(1 + a_n/n) = a_n\frac{\log(1 + a_n/n)}{a_n/n}$ when taking the limit $n\to \infty$ we have $a_n/n \to 0$ so you get the same limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \log(1+x)/x$ as you have in the $a_n = k$ case. The only new result you need to use is the basic limit result: if $A_n\to A$ and $B_n\to B$ then $A_nB_n \to AB$.

Comment: You're nearly there.  Since $a_n\rightarrow a$, for any $\epsilon>0$, for $n$ sufficiently large, $a-\epsilon<a_n<a+\epsilon$, so, you can squeeze between these by letting $\epsilon$ go to zero (perhaps replacing the limits with $\limsup$ and $\liminf$).

Comment: Right it all makes sense now. Thanks a lot you guys :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing new here, but perhaps streamlined a bit: Apply $\ln$ to get $$(1)\,\,\,\,n\ln (1+a_n/n)=\frac{\ln (1+a_n/n)}{a_n/n}\cdot a_n.$$ Now as $h\to 0,$ $\ln(1+h)/h = (\ln(1+h)-\ln 1)/h \to \ln'(1) = 1\,$ by definition of the derivative. It follows that the limit in (1) is $a.$ Exponentiating back gives the limit of $e^a$ as desired.

Comment: What if $a=0$ ? Because In that case some $a_n$ can be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach to the one by [@zhw.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/228045/zhw):

By the Mean Value Theorem, for sufficiently large $n$ (such that $1+\frac{a_n}{n} \neq 0$), there is a number $b_n$ between $1$ and $1+\frac{a_n}{n}$, i.e.,
$$\left\lvert b_n -1 \right\rvert \leq \left\lvert \frac{a_n}{n} \right\rvert = \left\lvert \left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right) - 1 \right\rvert,$$
such that
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right) - \ln(1) = \frac{1}{b_n} \cdot \frac{a_n}{n}.$$
Then,
$$n\ln\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right) \rightarrow \frac{a}{1} = a$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Therefore, by the continuity of $\exp$,
$$\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n = e^{n\ln\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)}\rightarrow e^a$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$, as desired.